# issues with pagination in a spring mvc project

Tags: jquery, hibernate, spring-mvc, displaytag

I have a Spring M V C project in which i have made use of the display tag pagination and the J-Query tabs as well. All is good but when i try paginating that is moving from page 1 to page 2 in any tab then the page is refreshed and the tab 1 is active again.
{if i paginate in the 2nd tab yet i am redirected to the first}

i am posting my code for reference ...
please help as soon as possible...

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/listquestions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getQuestions() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         List<Question> Answered=questionService.getAnswerQuestion();
         model.put("Answer", Answered);

         List<Question> unAnswer=questionService.getUnAnswerQuestion();
         model.put("unAnswer", unAnswer);   
    return new ModelAndView("jsp/AdminIndex", model);
}
```

D A O

```
 @Override
public List<Question> getUnAnswerQuestion() {
     session= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     Query query= session.createSQLQuery("select * from Question where ques_id not in (select ques_id from Answer) order by date desc");
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Question> list=query.list(); 
     return list;
 }

 @Override
    public List<Question> getAnswerQuestion() {
     session= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     Query query= session.createSQLQuery("select * from Question where ques_id in (select ques_id from Answer) order by date desc");
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Question> list=query.list(); 
     return list;
 }
```

Service

```
 @Override
public List<Question> getUnAnswerQuestion() {
    return questionDao.getUnAnswerQuestion();
}

@Override
public List<Question> getAnswerQuestion() {
    return questionDao.getAnswerQuestion();
}
```

View Page

```
      <div id="tabs" style="width: 650px">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Unanswered</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Answered</a></li>
        </ul>

<!-- Answered -->
        <div id="tabs-2">

             <display:table name="${Answer}" pagesize="10" sort="list" id="tmp3" requestURI="listquestions.html">

                 <display:column style="vertical-align:top;  padding-top: 7px; text-align: center; width: 75px; color:black;" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Username">
                    <a href="/gtlqa/getadmuserdet.html?uname=${tmp3[8]}"> <img src="/gtlqa/resources/images/userpic.gif" /></a><br>
                        ${tmp3[8]}
                </display:column>

                <display:column sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 7px; width: 465px;"  title="Question Title"> 
                    <a href="/gtlqa/getQuestionDet.html?quId=${tmp3[0]}"> <h3 style="color: #00c6ff"> ${tmp3[1]}</h3> </a>
                </display:column>

            </display:table> 
        </div>

<!-- Unanswered -->
        <div id="tabs-1">

             <display:table name="${unAnswer}" pagesize="10" sort="list" id="tmp2" requestURI="listquestions.html">

                 <display:column style="vertical-align:top;  padding-top: 7px; text-align: center; width: 75px; color:black;" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" title="Username">
                    <a href="/gtlqa/getadmuserdet.html?uname=${tmp2[8]}"> <img src="/gtlqa/resources/images/userpic.gif" /></a><br>
                        ${tmp2[8]}
                </display:column>

                <display:column sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 7px; width: 465px;"  title="Question Title"> 
                    <a href="/gtlqa/getQuestionDet.html?quId=${tmp2[0]}"> <h3 style="color: #00c6ff">  ${tmp2[1]}</h3> </a>
                </display:column>

            </display:table> 
        </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do something similar on my project - using multiple displaytag tables on the same page that are wrapped in tabbed div containers.

The trick is to:

1. **Capture the click events** of the pagination links in JavaScript
2. **Handle the click events** by fetching the next page via AJAX/XHR request (and stop the original event)
3. **Refactor your original page** so that each displaytag table is defined as an independent HTML fragment (i.e. its own JSP/page) that is *always* fetched via AJAX/XHR (i.e. also on load of parent/wrapper page)
4. **Handle the AJAX/XHR callback** by injecting the HTML fragment (response body) into the DOM of the parent/wrapper page

For #1 you will probably want to [register a click event listener](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for the element that wraps the whole paging banner (containing pagination links).

Then, for #2, inspect the [event target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to make sure an anchor tag (representing a pagination link) was clicked and [fire an AJAX GET request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the URL in the href of the anchor tag (since displaytag is building/managing the params on those URLs). Also make sure to prevent the click event from bubbling up the chain by doing something like [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). If you don't stop the event, the browser will handle the click as a normal link and reset the window's location to the pagination URL, which is what you describe in the OP and is not what you want.

For #3, move the content of your tab divs into their own JSPs and setup a separate URL/endpoint for each that will *(a)* fetch the data used by that displaytag table and *(b)* forward the request to the new JSP for writing the HTML response.

For #4, your JavaScript callback/success handler (function) should take the response body (which is HTML) and inject it into its parent container (the div representing the tab). To do this, just set the `innerHTML` property of the container element.

Note that, in general, this approach must be applied to **any** page that needs to contain more than one displaytag table with active *pagination* or *column sorting* links.